# Extending SSIS 2005 Packages with Custom Objects

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis, object

Am I right to be concerned about extending SSIS packages with custom objects? I accept custom objects can extend the functionality of SSIS and can reduce repetition & complexity within SSIS. Are there any guidelines as to when to use custom objects? What are the risks e.g. performance, maintainability etc? Where do I draw the line?

Answer (score 0):

SSIS can be extended with custom tasks and dataflows

I haven't done it myself but [sqlis.org has some downloads](http://sqlis.com/sqlis/category/Component-Downloads.aspx) (and lots of other stuff). Hope this helps